# How to create a protected routes in Next js with aws access token?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, token

I stored the aws access token in local storage and tried to create a higher order component. Check the token is present or not in local storage. It direct to login page when the token is missing. but dashboard page flashes for few seconds.

can Any one help to solve this..?

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using ReactJS and "amazon-cognito-identity-js" library to get along with AWS Cognito. So here is my answer.

You can try to store your authentication status a context component by trying getting session from local storage. Then you can try to read authentication status from your protected route and navigate to a desired page. Here are some codes:

```
// AuthContextProvider.js
import { createContext, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { CognitoUserPool } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
  UserPoolId: 'userPoolId', // Your user pool id here
  ClientId: 'clientId',
});

export const AuthContext = createContext({
  isAuthenticated: false,
});

const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
    isInitialized: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
  });

  const init = useCallback(() => {
    const cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

    if (cognitoUser) {
      cognitoUser.getSession((err, session) => {
        if (err) {
          setAuthState({
            isInitialized: true,
            isAuthenticated: false,
          });
          return;
        } else if (session) {
          // Authenticated successfully
          setAuthState({
            isInitialized: true,
            isAuthenticated: true,
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      setAuthState({
        isInitialized: true,
        isAuthenticated: true,
      });
    }
  }, []);

  // Try to read auth data on init
  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, [init]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...authState }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

Now in you App

```
import AuthContextProvider from './AuthContextProvider'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <Main></Main>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Your protected Route

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { isInitialized, isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (isInitialized && !isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/signin" />;
  }
  return <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Route component can look like:

```
<ProtectedRoute>
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>}>
</ProtectedRoute>
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Are you sure about this? This cannot be secure if the logic runs in the browser. One can simply edit these boolean values and access the “protected” route.

Comment: Thank you for the good hint. If you somehow edit these boolean, it triggers a state change and will re-render the page. While re-rendering, the authentication check run and set the authentication state again. So even you change the authentication boolean in the context to true, it doesn't matter. And also, you should have to authenticate token in backend as well, before giving out sensible data.